# Does the ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge (ILSVRC) definitely disappered?

Tags: classification, imagenet

#### A rather simple question:

I can not find a 2018 (neither a 2019) ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge (ILSVRC) for this particular dataset: http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/
It seems there is no information about the future of this challenge on this webpage.

I wonder if it has been definitely discarded because of too good results from competitors nowadays?

If yes, what are the other challenges that motivate scientific research in image classification or recognition tasks today (2019)?

Last available year was 2017: http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A simple answer:

As stated in their last new from the [2017 challenge webpage](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/index#news):
http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/index#news :

> Jul 26, 2017: We are passing the baton to [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/). From now on, all
>   three challenges(LOC-CLS, DET, VID) will be hosted on Kaggle!

it's now hosted on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) directly:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/imagenet-object-localization-challenge

It's also written on their home page normally (but I wasn't able to read it for some days):

> Check out the ImageNet Challenge on Kaggle!

http://image-net.org/